# Google Map not working inside FancyBox (lightbox)

Tags: google-maps, fancybox, lightbox

How do I get a Google Map to load inside the [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) lightbox? The map loads fine when not in the lightbox. I'm just using the standard Google maps code off their site:

```
 <html>
 <body>
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
 </body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8804280598958,
 174.811848958333);
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 13,
         center: myLatlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         panControl: false,
         zoomControl: false,
         scaleControl: true,
         mapTypeControl: false,
         scaleControl: false
     }
     var map = new
 google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); }

 function loadScript() {
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.src =
 "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
     document.body.appendChild(script); }

 window.onload = loadScript;
 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: probably need to resize when you open the lightbox. Go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ and go to the very bottom. It will talk about google maps. Could be the same problem here.